# Problems with pagination for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

My pagination links are failing for a custom post type here http://mjw.view-wireframes.com/about-us/press/

the page reloads http://mjw.view-wireframes.com/about-us/press/page/2/ but this has no effect on the displayed posts. Flushing the permalink structure has no effect so my guess is the problem is in the query.

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 10;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array( 'post_type' => 'press',
                                'orderby'   => 'post_date',
                                'posts_per_page' => $paged,
                                ));
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 



    // The following determines what the post format is and shows the correct file accordingly
    $format = get_post_format();
    get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/'.$format );

    if($format == '')
    get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/standard' );

endwhile;


global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );

$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Pagination function

```
<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?> 

function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class=\"theme-pagination\"><ul><li><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span></li>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><span><a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a></span></li>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><span><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a></span></li>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<li><span class=\"current\">".$i."</span></li>":"<li><span><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a></span></li>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><span><a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a></span></li>";
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><span><a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a></span></li>";
         echo "</ul></div>\n";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be using orderby date instead of post date!

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your `new WP_Query()` in a variable
2. *Globalize* `$wp_query`
3. Move the `$wp_query` swap-hack to *after* your `new WP_Query()` generation
4. Pass the *variable* to `$wp_query`, *not* the `new WP_Query()` call itself.

e.g.

```
<?php 
// Custom query args
$press_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'press',
    'orderby'   => 'post_date',
    //'showposts' => '10',
    'posts_per_page' => $paged,
);
// Custom query
$press_query = new WP_Query( $press_query_args );

// Globalize $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// Swap-hack
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = $press_query;

// Output custom loop
while ($press_query->have_posts()) : $press_query->the_post(); 

// EVERYTHING FROM HERE BELOW SHOULD BE THE SAME,
// THOUGH I'VE CLEANED IT UP A BIT
// (MAINLY, REMOVING THE CLOSE/OPEN PHP TAG COMBOS)

// The following determines what the post format is and shows the correct file accordingly
$format = get_post_format();
get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/'.$format );

if($format == '')
get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/standard' );

endwhile;  

if (function_exists("pagination")) {pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);} 

$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
?>
```

**EDIT**

Re: your pagination/post-per-page issue:

> Hi chip, thank you, but this produces some odd behavior, on the first page you see 10 articles and then pagination from pages 1-7, but on the second page you get the first two articles that appear on page 1 and the pagination numbering changes to go from 2-35

I suspect the problem lies here:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 10;
```

Couple with this array argument:

```
$wp_query->query(array( 
    'posts_per_page' => $paged,
));
```

**What happens if you remove `$paged` *and* the `'posts_per_page'` array argument?**

ALSO:

The pagination (1-7 vs 2-35) issue is probably separate from the posts-per-page issue (though perhaps related). Try to use `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()`, just to isolate the posts-per-page issue.

Comment: Hi chip, thank you, but this produces some odd behavior, on the first page you see 10 articles and then pagination from pages 1-7, but on the second page you get the first two articles that appear on page 1 and the pagination numbering changes to go from 2-35.

Comment: I believe that is a separate problem, possibly caused by this array key in your custom query args array: `'posts_per_page' => $paged,`?

Comment: Ah, I've changed that variable to 10 and commented that line of code out, it was referring a value set in the wordpress front end.

Comment: Where does the `pagination()` function come from? A Plugin (I assume), or custom Theme function?

Comment: It's a custom function to modify the way pagination displays, I've added the function code above.

Comment: Even removing the custom paginate function and using wordpress's own fails. Very confused.

Comment: Which WordPress pagination function(s) did you try? Also, have you removed both the `showposts` and `posts_per_page` keys from the custom query args array?

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to the current version. Thank you for your help by the way. I've been hacking at this all day and getting nowhere.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also: you indicate that you updated your original post with the modified code, but the custom query code all still looks the same as it was originally?

Comment: Ok, it's now using your code as posted above, no $paged and standard more/next links. but pagination still doesn't work, 10 items on the first page and the first two on the second page.

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate exactly what your current code is? It gets difficult trying to follow based only on comments.